# checkedlistbox vb.net event to check if selected

Tags: vb.net, events, checkedlistbox, handles

If I have a checkedlistbox with items (apple, carrot, frog) and a button that will only be enabled when at least one item is selected from the checkedlistbox, which event do I use?

where 'ListofURLFromDB_Listbox' is the checkedlistbox and 'Process_FromList_URLs_btn' is the button

I've tried .ItemCheck, .SelectedIndexChanged and .SelectedValueChanged

```
    If (ListofURLFromDB_Listbox.SelectedIndex = -1) Then
        Process_FromList_URLs_btn.Enabled = False
    ElseIf (ListofURLFromDB_Listbox.SelectedIndex > -1) Then
        Process_FromList_URLs_btn.Enabled = True
    End If
```

Many thanks

Comment: `Process_FromList_URLs_btn.Enabled = ListofURLFromDB_Listbox.CheckedItems.Count > 0` try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [SelectedIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event and count the number of checked items:

```
 Private Sub ListofURLFromDB_Listbox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListofURLFromDB_Listbox.SelectedIndexChanged
     If ListofURLFromDB_Listbox.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Process_FromList_URLs_btn.Enabled = True ' If checked items count is > 0
     Else
            Process_FromList_URLs_btn.Enabled = False
     End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks 'Raw N' that works great. I really appreciate your time